# Bash and filenames with spaces

Tags: bash, command-line

The following is a simple Bash command line:

```
grep -li 'regex' "filename with spaces" "filename"
```

No problems. Also the following works just fine:

```
grep -li 'regex' $(<listOfFiles.txt)
```

where `listOfFiles.txt` contains a list of filenames to be grepped, one
filename per line.

The problem occurs when `listOfFiles.txt` contains filenames with
embedded spaces. In all cases I've tried (see below), Bash splits the
filenames at the spaces so, for example, a line in `listOfFiles.txt`
containing a name like `./this is a file.xml` ends up trying to run
grep on each piece (`./this`, `is`, `a` and `file.xml`).

I thought I was a relatively advanced Bash user, but I cannot find a
simple magic incantation to get this to work. Here are the things I've
tried.

```
grep -li 'regex' `cat listOfFiles.txt`
```

Fails as described above (I didn't really expect this to work), so I
thought I'd put quotes around each filename:

```
grep -li 'regex' `sed -e 's/.*/"&"/' listOfFiles.txt`
```

Bash interprets the quotes as part of the filename and gives "No such
file or directory" for each file (and *still* splits the filenames with
blanks)

```
for i in $(<listOfFiles.txt); do grep -li 'regex' "$i"; done
```

This fails as for the original attempt (that is, it behaves as if the
quotes are ignored) and is very slow since it has to launch one 'grep'
process per file instead of processing all files in one invocation.

The following works, but requires some careful double-escaping if
the regular expression contains shell metacharacters:

```
eval grep -li 'regex' `sed -e 's/.*/"&"/' listOfFiles.txt`
```

Is this the only way to construct the command line so it will
correctly handle filenames with spaces?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try this:

```
(IFS=$'\n'; grep -li 'regex' $(<listOfFiles.txt))
```

`IFS` is the Internal Field Separator. Setting it to `$'\n'` tells Bash to use the newline character to delimit filenames. Its default value is `$' \t\n'` and can be printed using `cat -etv <<<"$IFS"`.

Enclosing the script in parenthesis starts a subshell so that only commands within the parenthesis are affected by the custom `IFS` value.

Comment: Even if you don't export it, the value will persist if this wasn't run in a subshell. Just try running `FOO=bar; echo $FOO` on one line, then `echo $FOO` on another. Subshells are automatically started for commands in pipelines, but `IFS=$'\n'` is of course not part of a pipeline here. The best solution is to surround the whole statement with parentheses, which manually tell bash to run the command in a subshell.

Comment: I still prefer running this in a subshell, but if you do want to save/restore IFS, you definitely want to quote the variable expansions.

Comment: Another way to have a variable assignment only apply temporarily is to use a space between the variable assignment and the command it applies to: `IFS=$'\n' grep -li 'regex' $(<listOfFiles.txt)`

Comment: @Dennis: I thought that as well, but for some reason that does not work on my machine. Perhaps that the scope of `IFS=$'\n'` is so limited in this case, that it doesn't even apply to `$(<listOfFiles.txt)`?

Comment: @Dennis: that doesn't work because the environment is only set after the processing of the argument list - so 'grep' sees the correct value of IFS, but the shell that is processing the argument list does not.

Comment: Was the last edit, by "sweatybridge", correct? That is, the command line (with or without the `$`).

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes that change seems correct. What issue do you face with the latest change that didn't affect the penultimate revision? (I tested the expression like this: `seq 0 9 | xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo {} > "{} {}.txt"; echo "{} {}.txt" >> listOfFiles.txt' && (IFS=$'\n'; grep -li '[0-5]' $(<listOfFiles.txt))`.

Answer (score 9):

```
cat listOfFiles.txt |tr '\n' '\0' |xargs -0 grep -li 'regex'
```

The -0 option on xargs tells xargs to use a null character rather than white space as a filename terminator.  The tr command converts the incoming newlines to a null character.

This meets the OP's requirement that grep not be invoked multiple times.  It has been my experience that for a large number of files avoiding the multiple invocations of grep improves performance considerably.

This scheme also avoids a bug in the OP's original method because his scheme will break where listOfFiles.txt contains a number of files that would exceed the buffer size for the commands.  xargs knows about the maximum command size and will invoke grep multiple times to avoid that problem.

A related problem with using xargs and grep is that grep will prefix the output with the filename when invoked with multiple files.  Because xargs invokes grep with multiple files one will receive output with the filename prefixed, but not for the case of one file in listOfFiles.txt or the case of multiple invocations where the last invocation contains one filename.  To achieve consistent output add /dev/null to the grep command:

```
cat listOfFiles.txt |tr '\n' '\0' |xargs -0 grep -i 'regex' /dev/null
```

Note that was not an issue for the OP because he was using the -l option on grep; however it is likely to be an issue for others.

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
while read file; do grep -li dtw "$file"; done < listOfFiles.txt
```

Comment: This does not address the OP's concern that grep be invoked a minimal number of times to maintain performance.  That is, multiple files on one command line.

Answer (score 1):

With Bash 4, you can also use the builtin mapfile function to set an array containing each line and iterate on this array:

```
$ tree
.
├── a
│   ├── a 1
│   └── a 2
├── b
│   ├── b 1
│   └── b 2
└── c
    ├── c 1
    └── c 2

3 directories, 6 files
$ mapfile -t files < <(find -type f)
$ for file in "${files[@]}"; do
> echo "file: $file"
> done
file: ./a/a 2
file: ./a/a 1
file: ./b/b 2
file: ./b/b 1
file: ./c/c 2
file: ./c/c 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it may overmatch, this is my favorite solution:

```
grep -i 'regex' $(cat listOfFiles.txt | sed -e "s/ /?/g")
```

Comment: This is terrible! and, errr, useless use of `cat` spotted!

Answer (score 0):

Do note that if you somehow ended up with a list in a file which has Windows line endings, `\r\n`, NONE of the notes above about the input file separator `$IFS` (and quoting the argument) will work; so make sure that the line endings are correctly `\n` (I use `scite` to show the line endings, and easily change them from one to the other).

Also `cat` piped into `while file read ...` seems to work (apparently without need to set separators):

```
cat <(echo -e "AA AA\nBB BB") | while read file; do echo $file; done
```

... although for me it was more relevant for a "grep" through a directory with spaces in filenames:

```
grep -rlI 'search' "My Dir"/ | while read file; do echo $file; grep 'search\|else' "$ix"; done
```