# Imgopt can't optimize file with whitespace in the name

Tags: linux, image, bash, optimization

Hy,

I'm trying to optimize the uploaded pictures on my webserver, with [imgopt](https://github.com/kormoc/imgopt). The problem is that, when it finds a file with whitespace in the name, it throw error like that:

```
$imgopt file - name.jpg
stat: cannot stat 'file': No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat 'name.jpg': No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks, Dave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use 'imgopt' but you'll have to rename your files with a command like this:

```
find your_folder -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename 's/ /_/g' "{}" \;
```

See the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709458/bash-script-to-replace-spaces-in-file-names) for more details about renaming directories, etc...

*Second answer:* you can also pass file names with spaces with a command like this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7535704/2327328)):

```
for fname in "$@"; do
  process-one-file-at-a-time "$fname"
done
```

Comment: Thanks. Before rename, I have to copy to a tmp dir, cause it's an online website, and we don't want some broken pictures ;).

Comment: Good, then renaming isn't an issue. I added a second answer that allows you to pass files with whitespace in their names to another command.

Comment: With renaming, it works good, just have to copy to a temp folder and rename after optimize to the original file name (I replaced thw whitespaces with ";something;" so it is easy to find the olda whitespaces). In other way, it's a bit safer, in case of the optimizer makes a mistake! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're actually passing three options to the `imgopt` program :

- `file`
- `-`
- `name.jpg`

The program probably treats each one of them as a separate file name (with `-` being `stdin`, following the standard Unix convention) and tries to open them. This, of course, fails. What you want are quotes :

```
imgopt "file - name.jpg"
```

This way, only one argument is given to the program and it contains a valid filename, with all the whitespace-y goodness.

Comment: The script is borked (assuming that we're talking about https://raw.github.com/kormoc/imgopt/master/imgopt ). It doesn't properly pass filenames with whitespace to other programs that it uses (`stat` and `file` stand out the most) - by forgetting to use quotes. You're best off chucking that sorry excuse of a script and manually launching the programs that it launches.