# Cut a file whose name contains a space

Tags: file, shell, cut

There is a file `/home/tiger/Desktop/shell practice`. I want to cut 9 blank spaces from it:

```
cut -c 10- '/home/tiger/Desktop/shell practice'
cut: /home/tiger/Desktop/shell practice: No such file or directory
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Because single quote should work even if the file name has a space.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574898/bash-and-filenames-with-spaces

Comment: Are you sure you have the name right? Try typing `cut -c 10- '/home/tiger/Desktop/shell` then TAB; it should auto-complete the file name, with backslashes added to escape any spaces. Also try `ls /home/tiger/Desktop | cat -A`

Comment: It should work, check the file name or file existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cut -c 10- '/home/tiger/Desktop/shell\ practice'
```

A friend told me how to solve it.