# substitute a text pattern in a bunch of files?

Tags: macos, bash, sed

File list contains a few thousands filenames like:

```
./folder/folder/file.ext
```

For each item of the list I should edit a file: substitute text pattern "old_text_pattern" by "new_text_pattern".
This command:

```
cat filelist | while read line; do sed -i 's/END_CREDIT_END/END_CREDIT/g' "$line"; done
```

gives an error:

```
sed: 1: "./folder ...": invalid command code .
```

How to perform the substitution properly? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is Linux and not OS X?

Comment: If any of the filenames contain spaces this will not work.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1574898/18157

Comment: @that other guy, you're right, it's os x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X `sed -i` is not like GNU `sed -i`. OS X's requires an argument.

```
cat filelist | while IFS= read -r line
  do sed -i bak 's/END_CREDIT_END/END_CREDIT/g' "$line"
done
```